# Grouping and aggregating field in single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

I have a table laid out as follows:

Table Name: TRANSACTIONS

```
transactionId | accountId | technology
--------------------------------------
1             | 1         | mac
2             | 1         | linux
3             | 2         | pc
4             | 3         | linux
5             | 2         | pc
6             | 3         | linux
...
```

I'd like to generate a report with the following format

```
accountId | num. pc | num. mac | num. linux
-------------------------------------------
1         | 1       | 1        | 0         
2         | 1       | 0        | 1
3         | 0       | 0        | 2
...
```

I'm not a SQL expert, but I feel I should be able to use a `GROUP BY` clause to generate these results. Would it be possible to generate this result set in a single query? I am using MS SQL Server 2008 at the moment, so T-SQL works.

Thanks!!

Comment: Wait. Are you asking to regenerate a new table that looks like this?
Or the resulting query to come out in this format?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I'm looking for the query to generate that result set.

Comment: Will the Technology field always be limited to those three values?

Comment: Pivot should work better in this case.

Comment: @AHiggins Yes, more or less. New technologies may be added, but I should be able to update the query when they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this

```
SELECT
   accountId ,
   [num. pc] = SUM(CASE WHEN  technology = 'pc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
   [num. mac] = SUM(CASE WHEN  technology = 'mac' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
   [num. linux] = SUM(CASE WHEN  technology = 'linux' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY accountId
```

Comment: If you go with this code, I'd recommend adding an 'other' bucket to catch any technologies that aren't accounted for in this list.